# What aspect oriented language is a good place to start for a c++ programmer

Tags: c++, aop

The only one I know of is called "e" which is used for test bench design in hardware design and verification but I want something for general purpose programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspect oriented programming isn't so much a defining feature of a language, it's a paradigm that can be applied to many existing programming languages.  You'd be hard-pressed to find a specific language that's aspect oriented in nature, though one could exist that makes adding cross-cutting concerns easy out of the box.  Starting with [Wikipedia's entry on Aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming#Implementations) should point you to several implementations specifically for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's a few limitations - C# can be used for AOP.

You might want to look [at c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raviraj.bhalerao/aop12062005022058AM/aop.aspx) and [developerfusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5307/aspect-oriented-programming-using-net/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Aspect C++](http://www.aspectc.org/) (not that I ever tried it)

Answer (score 0):

If you know e, then try VCS, which supports aspect-oriented extensions to SystemVerilog.

:-)